# Android Kotlin - requireContext() throws IllegalStateException inside Android Fragment's onViewCreated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-context, illegalstateexception

I am dealing with IllegalStateException crashes pertaining to the usage of getString in onViewCreated; looking at the stack trace this goes back through getResources into requireContext, which throws IllegalStateException if context is null.

I could probably resolve this by using getContext() and checking for nullability but this leads me to ask if there are certain scenarios where context is null in the onViewCreated step of a Fragment's lifecycle.

My stack trace is also showing these crashes happening inside my CoroutineScopes defined inside onViewCreated.

I would appreciate any feedback on this subject if available, as looking through the code, I'm calling getString function properly without any strange placements such as after navigation. Below is the stack trace. I'm running this app on an Android 13 device. Thanks.

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getString (Fragment.java:1053)
  at com.example.MyFragment$onViewCreated$1$2.invokeSuspend (MyFragment.kt) //this leads me to think inside Coroutines is where its crashing.
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (ContinuationImpl.kt)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.kt)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8757)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:604)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Comment: It shouldn’t be possible for it to be null in onViewCreated, but from the stack trace we can see it’s happening in a coroutine, not in onViewCreated. Maybe you can share the code where this coroutine is launched.

Comment: Actually it looks to me from the trace that you manually called onViewCreated yourself, which is forbidden and would cause the issue.

Comment: Definitely double checked and aside from overriding onViewCreated and calling super.onViewCreated on the very first line of the function, there is no other instance of calling itself from within.

As for the coroutine, its honestly too large, and I can't really share it due to sensitive information in it. I can say however, that I'm making liberal use of CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch to handle network calls via suspend functions, with responding to those functions if there is an error response I show an alertDialog that uses getString.

Comment: For added context, this application is portrait orientation only, and each fragment is part of a navigation graph in a single activity in a view-based approach, so no Jetpack Compose.

Comment: “CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch”. That is an anti pattern and would definitely cause the issue you’re seeing. Use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`  I can write an answer later to explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace is not pointing to `onViewCreated`. Notice the function name in the trace is actually `onViewCreated$1$2`. This is a virtual function name created for a coroutine you launched from within `onViewCreated`. So the crash is occurring some time after `onViewCreated`, and presumably after `onDetach` so the context is null at that point.

It's an anti-pattern to create a CoroutineScope and immediately launch a coroutine from it without first storing the CoroutineScope in a property so you can cancel it when the stuff it works with goes out of scope. You're creating a global coroutine, and might as well use GlobalScope. `CoroutineScope().launch` is a code smell because it's a global coroutine not launched in GlobalScope, which suggests the author isn't sure of what they're doing.

There are occasional uses for global coroutines, but in the vast majority of cases, you don't want your coroutine to be global. A coroutine usually works with stuff for more than a few milliseconds, so you want to be cancelling it if the work it's doing  is becoming obsolete to avoid wasting resources and memory for longer than necessary. Even more importantly, there are cases like yours, where you are trying to get a Context when its no longer available so you trigger a crash.

Android Fragments already provides `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` that you can launch coroutines from. It will automatically cancel all the coroutines it has launched when the Fragment view is destroyed, which protects you from holding onto obsolete view references for longer than necessary or trying to get a context when it is no longer available.

It should also be rare to launch a coroutine using `Dispatchers.IO`, especially on Android, where so many classes demand that they only be touched on the main thread. `Dispatchers.Main` should be your default, and it already is the default for `lifecycleScope`. `Dispatchers.IO` is for calling *blocking* code. You generally should only be using it with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }` to wrap bits of blocking code inside your coroutines.

Also note that suspend functions are not blocking if they are following convention. They internally use whichever threads/dispatchers they need so they never need to be wrapped in `withContext` when called.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive writeup. I'll take a look into viewLifecycleOwner.lifecyleScope and see if I can do a major refactor on my code, as I've been using CoroutineScope().launch extensively without making it a GlobalScope coroutine for the reasons you mentioned above, but it seems I've been mistaken at how it works.
As for Dispatchers.IO, I'm not sure if I want to be using it while blocking for network requests and responses. I've made use of suspend functions to await their completion in the coroutine.
Also, can Dispatchers.Main thread be used for making network calls?

Comment: If you are making a blocking call, such as a synchronous network call, that does need to be on Dispatchers.IO. If you're doing that directly in a coroutine, then you would wrap it in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }`. In practice, this is more likely to be done within some suspend function since it's lower level probably than what you're doing at the top level in a coroutine, if you're practicing common OOP principles about complexity and modularity. You cannot call *blocking* network functions on Dispatchers.Main, but calling *suspending* network functions is fine.

Comment: In reality, you shouldn't be making network calls in the Fragment at all if you're following the single responsibility principle, or the MVVM or MVC design patterns. The fragment works with UI. Network calls are normally done in a different layer of the app. You're at risk of "spaghetti code" if you try to do UI and data management in the same class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will mark this as the accepted answer as this is a new avenue for me to look into.

Comment: What is your opinion on having a CoroutineScope.launch() inside of a lifecycleObserver instance's onStop overridden function that uses an Activity's lifecycle object? I can't use lifecycle.coroutineScope here because it would be cancelled due to the lifecycle being destroyed, but I need for this instance I'm doing right now: to delete a file in system cache after the next activity grabs the content of that file using its URI content path after a set 3 second delay.
I don't want to make a new question about this since right now it does work as intended, but could it have drawbacks later?

Comment: It makes sense to use a global coroutine for the purpose of doing something you would never cancel and doesn't capture references to things in the Activity or Fragment. But then, why not use the already existing GlobalScope? I mean, it doesn't hurt to use `CoroutineScope()` instead of `GlobalScope`, although the documentation says not to do that, but it might cause someone reviewing the code to wonder if you knew what you were doing. Using GlobalScope shows you intended for the coroutine to be global.

Comment: Not sure I understand the 3 second thing--if you're waiting 3 seconds to give some other task "probably enough time" to complete some task, that seems a bit sketchy, but I guess there are times when there's not a better choice when dealing with the Android lifecycle. Even LiveData does this under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm attempting to do I'm unable to leverage the usual ViewModel and LiveData approach to share data, so for now I believe this is unavoidable. As long as the coroutine I'm planning to use is not meant to be cancellable, I think I can try changing it to globalScope and avoid passing references like context into the customLifecycleObserver. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

// Either Check if the fragment is attached to a valid context

```
    if (getContext() != null) {
```

// Now you can safely access resources and perform other operations

```
  val yourString = getString(R.string.your_string_resource)

    }
```

or you can also  check with

requireActivity().

Comment: I can do this as a last resort, but this question is primarily asking if it is possible for requireContext to be null inside onViewCreated.

Comment: This is kind of a hack that masks bugs by silently doing nothing.